# Openshift Multiple routers for an application

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

We want to spinup 5 pods for an application deployed in Openshift cluster.
We want to configure 2 routes for the same application.

```
For e.g. Pod1, Pod2 & Pod3 can be reached using route1
         Pod4 & Pod5 can be reached using route2..
```

Is it possible to configure two different routes for multiple pods

Comment: If you use statefulset instead of DeploymentConfig, it is possible

Comment: What problem is this trying to solve? All 5 of those pods should be identical. The only way to do this is have two DeploymentConfigs that apply different labels to their pods.

Comment: Why not just add another DeploymentConfig that has pod4 and pod5? Are you trying to do some sort of progressive deployment? (canary or blue/green?)

Answer (score 0):

Is this DeploymentConfig consist of 5 replicas. Then it is not possible to create separate routes for different pods. You have to create separate DeploymentConfigs to be able to create separate routes for different pods.

Comment: Yes DeploymentConfig consist of 5 replicas.. So If i create seperate DeploymentConfig, then i think it becomes a dfferent application. I wanted to avoid deploying multiple applications

Comment: I don't think Openshift can help you with that.

Comment: @user3811946 It is not a different application if the two DeploymentConfig's have mirrored configuration.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible but you need to do little hack.

1. Deploy 5 pods.
2. create two services and one route for each service
3. service one uses selector say, 'mypod:123' and second service selects pod with label 'mypod:45'
4. Patch unique label say 'mypod:123' to pod1, pod2, pod3
5. Patch label 'mypod:45' to pod 4 and 5

It is not a recommended approach but it should work.

the limitation of this approach is that if a pod gets terminated a new one gets spinned up, you need to manually patch the pod with correct label.

to avoid manual intervention , suggest you to go with two separate deployments